# 2wpf .net5 error The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I create a new project in Visual Studio 2019  and select "WPF Application" .net5 and tries to build the generated application, I get the tow errors

> The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context.

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.

I see all similar questions and try all solutions
What is wrong?
[image: error]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
}

<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer exactly without the code.
It is very likely that you have created a namespace confusion.
You will show your XAML "App", "MainVindow" and Code Behind "MainWIndow".
It is possible not completely, but the first lines where classes, constructors and namespaces are declared.

Comment: I create a new wpf project  without any new code and the proplem appear

Comment: I repair visual studio and .net5  and the error still

Comment: Everything is correct in these codes.
Try to create new Solution - maybe some random bug.
If it does not help, then need to understand entirely the Solution and the Visual Studio settings.

Comment: I create many solution and the error still

Comment: Can you include the code for  App.xaml also

Comment: Does this also happen when you close your project, delete the obj-directory from the wpf-project, reopen the project and rebuild ? it seems like the hidden code-behind files for 'App' aren't generated properly

Answer (score 1):

I created an empty Solution and archived it on Google Disk [Empty Application](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ztSBiwCOzM5MN6ckkWNTOD1yT2MfPvtI/view?usp=sharing)
Download it and try to open it in Visual Studio.
If it opens, it means that you either have the wrong type of project, or there is an error in the templates for creating the Solution.
If it does not open, then there is a problem with the Studio itself.

Report the result in order to understand in which direction to look for a solution to your problem.

Comment: I download your empty project  and run the code same problem have occurred , I repair visual studio and  same problem have occurred

Comment: I open the empty project with rider same problem have occurred

Comment: I don't know what the problem might be.
But this is related to your computer, OS settings, applications installed on it.